# Existe alguma maneira de submeter o formulário para um Iframe (sem Javascript)?

Tags: html, formulário, iframe

Existe alguma maneira de fazer uma submissão de formulário onde o `action`, ao invés de atualizar a página, seja submetido a um `iframe`?

Já vi isso em algum lugar, mas não soube como a mágica foi feita. Foi feito sem Javascript.

Algo  parecido com:

```
<form action="/my_page" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<!-- o resultado deve ser exibido aqui, ao invés de atualizar a página -->
<iframe></iframe>
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, existe uma maneira de submeter um formulário para um `iframe`, sem necessidade de Javascript.

Muita gente não sabe, mas é possível.

Primeiro é preciso definir o atributo `target` em seu `form`. Esse `target` deverá apontar para o `iframe` desejado. Sendo assim, você precisa definir um `name` para o `iframe` onde deseja que a submissão seja processada. Em seguida, no `form` você define o atributo `target` com o valor do `name` atribuído ao `iframe`.

Veja:

```
<form action="/my_page" method="POST" target="target_iframe">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<!-- o resultado deve ser exibido aqui, ao invés de atualizar a página -->
<iframe name="target_iframe"></iframe>
```

No caso acima, o resultado da submissão que vai ser processado na url `/my_page` seria exibido dentro do `iframe` **sem que ocorrece atualização (refresh) da página**.